# Error 404. The requested page (/en/index.php) was not found in nopCommerce 4.00

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, nopcommerce, error-log

Getting Continues 404-Errors in the log on every request.

Error log as below :

Log level : Error
Short message :

> Error 404. The requested page (/en/index.php) was not found

Customer : `builtin@search_engine_record.com`
Page URL : http://www.example.com/en/index.php?menu=requestlogin&session_id=6isquntqq70mosiudb3638ipq5&user_type=1

Please let me know how to fix this error.

Comment: How are you running your nopCommerce store with php?

Comment: We dont have php page even then also getting error in logs

Comment: That is weird! seem like some plugin cause the issue, are you using any third party plugin?

Comment: Have you got the solution for this problem ? I'm also getting such messages in my error log.

Comment: i used url block plugin

Answer (score 0):

It is just a web crawler looking for pages at your site. It is not under your control. It is likely hacker script blindly looking for known frameworks and exploits or a legitimate service like builtwith.com performing a technology survey.

Maybe you could block the originating ip, but checking if you're running php doesn't seem really dangerous so you can safely ignore it.

Comment: How can remove url from web crawler ?

Comment: Updated answer.